# How To connect Ionic 3 (Angular 5) app to Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, azure-sql-database

I have an MS Access frontend working with an Azure SQL database as the backend.  This all works fine.

The next step is to give some functionality to remote users on mobiles and tablets via an Ionic App.

What is the best way to make an Ionic app interact (READ/WRITE) data with an Azure SQL database?

I am just looking for an initial overview to get a starting position.  I would like to keep it within MS Azure if possible.

Is an Azure App the way to go to work as the interface between the two?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Ionic which allows connection to 'Easy Tables' in the Azure App Service.  We found that in order to be able to connect an Access FE to the same tables that we had to make a new SQL db with the usual setup before adding the Easy Tables.  If you make the Easy tables first, Azure doesn't show you the SQL database that these relate to and how to connect to it using the standard SQL ODBC connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider having an API which can speak to Azure DB and have NativeScript app to call the API using REST if you are considering real-time option. You can create an Azure Mobile that uses NativeScript as explained [here](http://nuvious.com/Blog/2015/3/21/using-nativescript-with-azure-mobile-services).

To create a REST API with Azure SQL Database please consider [this](https://medium.com/@jocapc/creating-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-sql-server-azure-sql-4933fd3fb2be) article.

Comment: Thanks Alberto.  I have voted your answer up but it doesn't show I'm afraid.

Comment: The Ionic dev is using Azure Easy Tables.  Is it possible to connect an Access FE to these like a regular SQL database tables?  If not, which different Azure backend need to be used?

Comment: I am happy if you find it useful. Thank you for your kindness. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: I have helped some users that use Azure SQL Database as backend of an Access Front End but I have not seen an Azure Easy Table as backend of Access. I will investigate to see if I can share something with you about Access & Azure Easy tables.

Comment: Thanks Alberto, that was interesting reading.  In the end we found a plugin for Ionic which allowed us to connect to 'Easy Tables' in the Azure App Service. 

We found that in order to be able to connect an Access FE to the same tables that we had to make a new SQL db with the usual setup before adding the Easy Tables.  If you make the Easy Tables first, Azure doesn't show you the SQL database that these relate to and how to connect to it using the standard SQL ODBC connection string.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to your own question. It will help others in the future. Do no leave your solution here in the comments area.

Comment: OK @AlbertoMorillo, will do.  Thanks again for your help.